# Check the keys in the nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to check the keys in my nested dictionary and add the keys/values accordingly.
Lets say, for example I have the following

```
mydict = [{'GradeA' : {'kim' : '10'}}, {'GradeB' : {'Patrick' : 'val23'}, {'Putty' : 'val40'}}, {'GradeC' : {'John' : 'val8'}}, {'GradeD' : {'Tim' : 'Val5'}}]
```

if the input key is GradeD, Kate val50. Then it should add to that key as follows:

```
       mydict= [{'GradeA' : {'kim' : '10'}}, {'GradeB' : {'Patrick' : 'val23'}, {'Putty' : 'val40'}}, {'GradeC' : {'John' : 'val8'}}, {'GradeD' : {'Tim' : 'Val5'}, {'Kate' : 'val50'}}]
```

If the input key is GradeE, Kim val27. Then it should look as follows:

```
       mydict= [{'GradeA' : {'kim' : '10'}}, {'GradeB' : {'Patrick' : 'val23'}, {'Putty' : 'val40'}}, {'GradeC' : {'John' : 'val8'}}, {'GradeD' : {'Tim' : 'Val5'}, {'Kate' : 'val50'}}, {'GradeE' : {'kim' : 'val27'}}]
```

If the input key is GradeA, kim val10. Then it should look as follows:

```
         mydict= [{'GradeA' : {'kim' : 'val10'}}, {'GradeB' : {'Patrick' : 'val23'}, {'Putty' : 'val40'}}, {'GradeC' : {'John' : 'val8'}}, {'GradeD' : {'Tim' : 'Val5'}, {'Kate' : 'val50'}}, {'GradeE' : {'kim' : 'val27'}}]
```

Pleased to hear some suggestions. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I think you mistakenly wrote GradeB twice here - ```mydict = [{'GradeA' : {'kim' : '10'}}, {'GradeB' : {'Patrick' : 'val23'}}, {'GradeB' : {'Putty' : 'val40'}}, {'GradeC' : {'John' : 'val8'}}, {'GradeD' : {'Tim' : 'Val5'}}]``` as it conflicts with your next line. I think you mean to capitalize the 'k' in 'kim'. This would change the solution. Clean up the question and I will remove my downvote and answer it. Best of luck

Comment: @Jake Denham-Dyson - Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your first statement.

```
mydict = [{'GradeA' : {'Kim' : '10'}}, {'GradeB' : {'Patrick' : 'val23'}, {'Putty' : 'val40'}}, {'GradeC' : {'John' : 'val8'}}, {'GradeD' : {'Tim' : 'Val5'}}]
```

Which I am assuming should read

```
mydict = [{'GradeA' : {'Kim' : '10'}}, {'GradeB' : {'Patrick' : 'val23', 'Putty' : 'val40'}}, {'GradeC' : {'John' : 'val8'}}, {'GradeD' : {'Tim' : 'Val5'}}]
```

You have not addressed the typo 'kim' if it is supposed to be a typo? In my answer I have assumed it was a mistake, if it was not a mistake a conversion to lowercase would be necessary and some sort of comparison would need to be made.

The below code first checks if the particular grade exists, if it does the entry is added to the contained dictionary. If it does not then a new grade and entry is added to the list.

```
my_list = [{'GradeA' : {'Kim' : '10'}}, {'GradeB' : {'Patrick' : 'val23', 'Putty' : 'val40'}}, {'GradeC' : {'John' : 'val8'}}, {'GradeD' : {'Tim' : 'Val5'}}]

def manageList(grade, name, value):
    search_list = False
    for item in my_list:
        if list(item.keys())[0] == grade:
            item[grade][name] = value
            search_list = True
        else:
            pass
    if search_list: 
        pass        
    else:
        my_list.append({grade: {name: value}})  

manageList('GradeD', 'Kate', 'val50')
print(my_list)
manageList('GradeE', 'Kim', 'val27')
print(my_list)
manageList('GradeA', 'Kim', 'val10')
print(my_list)
```

Output

```
[{'GradeA': {'Kim': '10'}}, {'GradeB': {'Patrick': 'val23', 'Putty': 'val40'}}, {'GradeC': {'John': 'val8'}}, {'GradeD': {'Tim': 'Val5', 'Kate': 'val50'}}]
[{'GradeA': {'Kim': '10'}}, {'GradeB': {'Patrick': 'val23', 'Putty': 'val40'}}, {'GradeC': {'John': 'val8'}}, {'GradeD': {'Tim': 'Val5', 'Kate': 'val50'}}, {'GradeE': {'Kim': 'val27'}}]
[{'GradeA': {'Kim': 'val10'}}, {'GradeB': {'Patrick': 'val23', 'Putty': 'val40'}}, {'GradeC': {'John': 'val8'}}, {'GradeD': {'Tim': 'Val5', 'Kate': 'val50'}}, {'GradeE': {'Kim': 'val27'}}]
```